# How to replace part of a declarative Jenkinsfile pipeline variable to get the name of the job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to get the name of the Jenkins job.  The name is a Jenkins environmental variable called JOB_NAME (and which looks like `project_name/branch`).  JOB_BASE_NAME strips off the `project_name/`, leaving `branch`.

I want to get `project_name`.

I thought there might be something like this I could do:

```
environment {
  NAME = "${env.JOB_NAME}.replaceAll(~/\/.*$/, '')
}
```

and then use `${NAME}` later in the pipeline, but this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do `env.JOB_NAME - env.JOB_BASE_NAME` and then drop one character off the end of that if you need to lose the final `/`.

Once you've defined something in your `environment` closure, it should be accessible not as a normal variable like `NAME`, but instead like the predefined env variables, such as `env.NAME`